# Chrome Extension Add New Menu to System Tray Icon of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, system-tray

I want to add my extension options menu in system tray icon of Google chrome. I searched it a lot but not found even a hint. Here I saw one extension added it.
[image]

Could anyone help to explain that. I even have look into source code of that extension but didn't found answer. So finally here.

Comment: I suspect this is a result of `"background"` permission. Needs testing.

Answer (score 2):

This item appears if the following conditions are met:

- The extension requests [`"background"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background).
- Chrome settings allow "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed".

This menu item is mostly a reminder "what extensions/apps are keeping Chrome runtime running in backround". If no extensions meet the above critera, the Chrome icon doesn't appear at all.

If clicked, it has a fixed behavior that you can't change:

- If the extension has an options page defined, it's opened in a new tab, *even if it's the [new-style options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) that should be embedded in `chrome://extensions`*. That last point is [certainly a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666897).
- If the extension has no options page defined, it opens `chrome://extensions/` in a new tab.

Comment: love you, You just save my day. I tried it the whole day yesterday.